# Steady state approximation rate equation for an E1cB reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry

Is anyone able to explain why species 'D' is not included in the steady state approximation derivation for this E1cB reaction?

The correct rate equation in the image has been derived first and then I have added in the line I am confused about below

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Because it is the reaction solvent and is present in vast excess

Comment: The base is ethoxide in a solvent of ethanol. The concentration of ethanol is then essential constant and can be absorbed into rate constant $k_{-1}$.